# drug-dna concentration

Tags: dna, rna, pharmacology

I want to understand how you calculate the final concentration of a Drug-DNA complex. I tried to mix equal concentration and volume of drug and DNA to form a complex and tried to see the absorbance spectra using UV-VIS but saw very little peak for drug. I think I am doing something wrong to calculate the concentration.

Here is what I did.

I mixed 500uL of 20uM of DNA to 500ul of 20uM of drug. I expect to see a large absorbance peak but I see very small peak at the wavelength of that drug. My aim is to have a drug-DNA complex of 20 uM. Could anybody please explain to me how to calculate the final concentration. Any reference articles so that I can understand are greatly appreciated. Also, I want to understand the job plot where we can find the binding of the drug to DNA.

Comment: Hi, this isn't the right place for wet-lab trouble shooting. Biology SE is probably better

Comment: Your ratios assume 1:1 DNA:drug stoichiometry. Is that correct? What is the drug, and how is it expected to interact with DNA? Is it an intercalating agent? Is the DNA a single sequence of a fixed length or is it a mix of sequences of different lengths?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to check the number of base pair ligand is interacting with. DNA is double sequence and of fixed length. The ligand intercalates with DNA. I want to know what the feasible way is to do it.